# pip install fails when Installing build dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

Installing packages in my lovely locked-down IT environment

```
python -m pip --default-timeout=1000 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyautogui
```

Using this I am able to install packages such as `matplotlib` without any issue, however `pyautogui` fails with the following at the `Installing build dependencies` step :

```
 Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz (59 kB)
Collecting pymsgbox
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2
.....
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
.....
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can check network / firewalls / proxy issues. If that is ok then in pip help you can find a parameter for timeout. Try to increase the values for this:   --timeout  Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).